# Resources for Mixed IDE Debugger for intel fortran and python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, fortran

Is it possible to debug Fortran code that's wrapped in python?

Say with VS Code?

for example,

```
main.py - python 3.9
    foo.f90 - intel fortran
    bar.f90 - ditto
    baz.f90 - ditto
```

I'd like to be able to run the IDE using main.py and step through the foo.f90, bar.f90, baz.f90 with a debugger.

I have not tried anything yet into this, I wanted to ask the community prior to starting this effort.

Comment: Loosely related in concept but about Python and C++: https://nadiah.org/2020/03/01/example-debug-mixed-python-c-in-visual-studio-code/ and https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjamin-simmonds.pythoncpp-debug

Comment: It would be the same as Python and C++ since Fortran and C++ use the same debug adapter. FYI this would only work with GDB i.e. debug adapter `cppdbg` since Intel's Fortran compilers do not work with the Windows debug adapter. Best way to see if it will work is to try it yourself.